# Access query results for last 7 days on a SmallDateTime (SQL) table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have an Access frontend with an SQL Server backend.

I have a table with many records, with a smalltimedate column "Observed_date" (yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss).

I want to write a query to return all the records in the table for the last 7 days (i.e. BETWEEN Date() and Date()-7).

I understand I need to drop the "time" value on the column, so in my query I'm doing the following:

```
SELECT INT((table.field)) AS JustDate FROM table;
```

This returns just the date value for every record in the table.

But what do I do next to get just the last 7 days of records?

thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you don't need `between` for the last 7 days:

T-SQL

```
WHERE table.field >= CAST(GETDATE() - 7 AS DATE)
```

Access SQL

```
WHERE table.field >= Date() - 7
```

Comment: I had just done this: `SELECT Count(dbo_EventReport.Event_ID) AS CountOfEvent_ID FROM dbo_EventReport WHERE (((Format([dbo_EventReport].[Completed_Date],'yyyy-mm-dd')) Between Format(Date()+1,'yyyy-mm-dd') And Format(Date()-7,'yyyy-mm-dd')))` but your solution is much nicer. I had tried performing stuff on Date() before but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This will return all rows where `Observed_date` is higher or equal to current time - 7 days and time part is set to midnight:

```
WHERE
  Observed_date >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(d, '1900-01-01', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 7, CAST('00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME2(3)))
```